# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<RestaurantModel>'

Tags: flutter

I'm new to programming and currently learning JSON. I got this error when using Cubit to access the JSON:

```
RestaurantFailed(type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<RestaurantModel>')
```

JSON Sample: https://restaurant-api.dicoding.dev/list

I'm trying to access the API and insert it to RestaurantModel.

this is my code:
**restaurant_service.dart**

```
class RestaurantService {
  Future<List<RestaurantModel>> fetchAllData() async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.http('restaurant-api.dicoding.dev', '/list');
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      Map<String, dynamic> result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<RestaurantModel> restaurants = result['restaurants'].forEach((json) {
        return RestaurantModel.fromJson(json: json);
      });
      return restaurants;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

**restaurant_cubit.dart**

```
class RestaurantCubit extends Cubit<RestaurantState> {
  RestaurantCubit() : super(RestaurantInitial());

  void fetchData() async {
    try {
      emit(RestaurantLoading());
      List<RestaurantModel> restaurants =
          await RestaurantService().fetchAllData();
      emit(RestaurantSuccess(restaurants));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(RestaurantFailed(e.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

**restaurant_model.dart**

```
class RestaurantModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String pictureId;
  final String city;
  final double rating;
  String? address;
  List<String>? categories;
  List<String>? menus;
  List<CustomerReviewModel>? customerReviews;

  RestaurantModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.pictureId,
    required this.city,
    this.rating = 0.0,
    this.address = '',
    this.categories,
    this.menus,
    this.customerReviews,
  });

  factory RestaurantModel.fromJson({required Map<String, dynamic> json}) =>
      RestaurantModel(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        description: json['description'],
        pictureId: json['pictureId'],
        city: json['city'],
        rating: json['rating'].toDouble(),
        address: json['address'] ?? '',
        categories: json['categories'] ?? [],
        menus: json['menus'] ?? [],
        customerReviews: json['customerReviews'] ?? [],
      );
}
```

any feedback or input would be very appreciated! Cheers

Comment: Do you have a sample of the JSON?  Maybe the shape isn't a top level map with Lists for values.

Comment: this is the JSON source files: https://restaurant-api.dicoding.dev/list also add it on my question

Comment: `result['restaurants']` is known only to be a `dynamic`.  You need to cast it as a List to do .forEach on it.  In general, every layer will need an appropriate cast.  That is the nature of decoding from the type-less JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `forEach` should be replaced by `map(...).toList()` like the following code snippet:

```dart
      List<RestaurantModel> restaurants = result['restaurants'].map((json) {
        return RestaurantModel.fromJson(json: json);
      }).toList();
```

This is because `forEach` returns `void` and it cannot be assigned to anything. On the other hand, `map` returns a `Iterable<RestaurantModel>` and it's just a matter of converting it to list with the `toList()` method.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I got this error after changing the code.  RestaurantFailed(type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<RestaurantModel>')

Comment: It's just missing the <RestaurantModel> after .map thanks for the help!